# Lucid Install on Dell R320

Tags: drivers, server, system-installation, 10.04, dell

I'm looking for some specific help installing Lucid-64 on a Dell R320 Server.  Having never touched a Dell Server I am a LOT lost here.

Goal is to install company proprietary software on the server.  A server was chosen for hardness, not because it is a server, per se.  Previous test all done on a desktop and worked great.

First questions are BIOS config related:
1. Do I install with RAID enabled?  How do I select the RAID type?  I have 2 pairs of drives, 500GB and 1TB.  I want th eOS on the 500 GB pair.
2. Do I want logical processors?
3. Any other Bios changes that'd make things better.

The Ubuntu install CD gets as far as partioning the drives and shows no drives and no install partitions.  I'm guessing I'm missing a driver.  Looking at the Del site is a tad confusing as there are perhaps a dozen or more HDD drivers available, some for SATA some for SAS.  The Drives say SATA so I guess that's what I need.
1. Any recommendations on choice of driver?
2.  How do I tell the install CD to find the driver?  Even if it is on a USB key, how does the install see it?

I'm sure to have more questions.  But thanks for now.

Comment: Did you ever have any success installing on the R320? I'd be interested - have same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just found your question, 4 months late.  Yes, I did get it to install.  Without having to do anything special AFTER I got help from coworkers who knew hos to configure the BIOS and RAID and CONFIGURATION MANAGER.  Maddeningly complicated.  Once done it runs great!

Comment: And have a point for being patient and also, hopefully, to let you know to look here.

Comment: @WesMiller - care to share the "how to"? Because I never got it to play nicely with the "hardware raid", and resorted to AHCI & 2 single drives, using Linux software RAID.  That's w/ 1404 and 1604, not lucid, though.